# How to interpret rarefaction results?

Tags: statistical-significance, interpretation, biostatistics, diversity

I have applied rarefaction analysis with R's package iNext. I got these results:

```
     Site     Diversity         Observed Estimator    s.e.      LCL      UCL
     Healthy  Species richness  389.000  1516.770 235.736 1140.958 2080.404
     Healthy Shannon diversity   27.731    31.545   1.029   29.528   33.562
     Healthy Simpson diversity   10.407    10.428   0.277   10.407   10.971
      Tumour  Species richness  260.000   786.557 138.037  577.687 1132.753
      Tumour Shannon diversity   24.546    26.685   0.855   25.009   28.361
      Tumour Simpson diversity   11.241    11.270   0.270   11.241   11.799
  Metastasis  Species richness   12.000    43.964  39.554   16.835  223.333
  Metastasis Shannon diversity    1.195     1.218   0.044    1.195    1.304
  Metastasis Simpson diversity    1.056     1.056   0.011    1.056    1.078
```

How do I interpret the results?

There are 1516.770 (95% CI: 1140.958-2080.404) species in Healthy tissues? or 389.000 +/- 235.736? Similarly for the Shannon index.

Comment: I'll assume you are looking at something like species (e.g. metabolites or transcribed bits of RNA) in different tissue types. I'm not sure whether you rarefied by sample size (e.g. number of reads or the like) or by sample coverage (Chao and Jost 2012 Ecology), but in either case, the numbers represent the *expected* diversity (number of species, or Hill-Shannon or Hill-Simpson diversity), conditioned on a particular sample size. The "CI" are very approximate intervals (not true 95% CI) indicating the sampling uncertainty.  If the 1500 spp seems high, maybe check that you didn't transpose.

Comment: To get a feel for how the CI are constructed, check out Chao and Jost 2015 Methods in Ecology and Evolution (the details are in an appendix).